# Problems generating neat ionic template objects

Tags: ionic-framework, sass, ionic4, ion-grid

I am experimenting with a small detailed grid of tiles in ionic on mobile. Essentially a rough design wireframe looks like this:

[image: wireframe]

A few words on what I have drawn. Each item can be described a thumbnail, a title and an array of 'tiles'. Each tile should ideally appear as a fixed size item. Either embossed 3D or flat : whatever works. On each tile, there will be a number of very small accurately positions components: a number, an icon, some text, and optionally another icon / or more likely a very small image or a linear guage (just represented by 3 values - green / orange / red. Not a real guage).

I have tried using ion-card, but ion-grid does not work inside a card. And efforts to lay the items out with ion-grid have not worked either. I have found it is impossible to force the items to come close enough together. As the elements inside each column come close to filling the space, the grid expands and /or wraps. Since I'm working with dynamic data, it's never going to work reliably.

A really basic starting point that does work just describing a single tile :

```
<ion-row>
                  <ion-col class="ion-text-center" no-padding> 
                    <ion-label>  
                      <h5 card-body-text style="font-size: 0.8rem;" class="device-id-text">
                        TEMP
                      </h5>
                      <ion-text color="dark">                      
                        <h4 item-title class="device-name-text" style="font-size: 1.5rem;"> 
                          <ion-text color="primary"><span> {{ item.lastTemp}}  </span> </ion-text>
                        </h4> 
                      </ion-text>
                    </ion-label>
                  </ion-col>
```

[image: starting point]

As you can see the basic structure is kind of there. But it heavily relies on the content fitting inside the column for it to work. I can add an ion-icon too but that actually looks, well, not great. It's not really a good solution!

I can't figure out how to create a 'tile' and get the requisite elements into it such that they will look something like the desired outcome. How can this be accomplished in ionic. I am on ionic 4. If upgrading to ionic 5 or 6 would make this easier to do, then that could be part of the answer...

Comment: I believe you can do this with CSS. Moreover, you can do it without Ionic components.

Comment: @DanilProkhorenko Would you say ionic components are not capable enough to achieve this then? Would approach would you use?

Comment: I mean you can style all as you wish. And `I have found it is impossible to force the items to come close enough together.` is not true. You can style it too.